# make a randomizer from two list in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

My Code:

```
import random
import discord


color1 = [0xFFE4E1, 0x00FF7F, 0xD8BFD8, 0xDC143C, 0xFF4500, 0xDEB887, 0xADFF2F, 0x800000]
color2 = [0x4682B4, 0x006400, 0x808080, 0xA0522D, 0xF08080, 0xC71585, 0xFFB6C1, 0x00CED1]
color3 = random.choice(color1, color2)
color4 = color3

@bot.command()
async def color(ctx):
    embed=discord.Embed(title="Colorss", color=color4)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

i want it to come out as a random color from **color1** or **color2*

Error that I'm getting

```
TypeError: choice() takes 2 positional argument but 3 were given
```

Comment: `random.choice([color1+color2])`?

Comment: Or even `random.choice(color1+color2)`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

write `random.choice([color1, color2])`

Comment: This returns either the whole first or the whole second list

Comment: @mnikley and that's what Hamoood wants

Comment: @matebende he mentioned `a random color from color1 or color2`, also from the context of the code this would most likely return an error